# What happens with fractional shares in a stock swap.

Tags: investing

I own some shares of FOXA and with the recent announcement of the deal with Disney, I will receive .2745 shares of DIS for each share of FOXA I own. How is this handled? Will my brokerage account automatically reflect a balance of partial DIS shares?

Answer (score 4):

Normally any remainder from conversion into full shares will be compensated in cash.

Comment: This is typically denoted as **cash in lieu of fractional shares** on the receipt/statement from your broker.

Comment: And at least in the US, for tax purposes you are treated as receiving the fractional shares (along with the whole shares) and immediately selling them for the cash, which means you realize and must report a capital gain or loss using a pro-rata portion of the basis transferred from the old stock, with its holding period. Fortunately IME brokers would do this computation for you even before 2011 when the new basis-reporting law effectively requires it. Be glad the deal is all-stock; handling fractional shares on stock-plus-cash is even worse.